# how to use --data-binary in bash curl command with multi params

Tags: bash, curl

```
<?php
$post_data = array(
    'filename'=>new \CurlFile($uploadPath),
    'jsondata'=> json_encode($params,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)
$toPdfApi='https://example.com/convert2PDF'
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$toPdfApi);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'multipart/form-data',
        'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_data);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
```

Then I convert it to bash shell command

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" --data-binary  'filename=@/root/test.txt' --data-binary   'jsondata={"fileName":"test","id":"xxx","backlink":"https://example.com/hello"}' https://example.com/convert2PDF
```

But the reponse result still not right

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 01 Jun 2018 14:41:37 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.4.5.v20170502)

error
```

Can someone help ? is it my covert bash shell right?

if I use the following command [replace -data-binary to -F ], I get the right status ,but from the  php code I know I should add the CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER in bash curl ,otherwise the https://example.com/convert2PDF can not get the right post data.

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -F  'filename=@/root/test.txt' -F   'jsondata={"fileName":"test","id":"xxx","backlink":"https://example.com/hello"}' https://example.com/convert2PDF

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 01 Jun 2018 16:29:35 GMT
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.4.5.v20170502)

success
```

I want to get the reponse's status is 200 ,and the result is success in --data-binary mode ,What can I do to udpate my bash command ?

Comment: Think you could add what you *are* getting vs. what you expect?

Comment: @Jason Update the descrbie . Give some advice if you are conviniece ,thanks a lot .

Comment: Is that top code block the contents of text.txt?

Comment: @json ,Yes , the variable $uploadPath is the path of  text.txt

Answer (score 6):

The whole point of `--data-binary` is that it's one big lump of bytes. You can only send one as each HTTP request only has one body and can only have one top-level content type.

What it seems you're trying to do is construct a multi-part request body that has two parts, one containing file data and one containing key/value pairs.

To send a file with some metadata over command line, you can do this:

```
curl -F'id=xxx' -F 'name=foo' -F'file=@test.txt;type=text/plain' http://example.com
```

That will send a multi-part request where a PHP backend could access the metadata from $_POST and the file data from $_FILES.

The exact approach required would depend on what the back end expects to receive but you've not posted that.

For example, the following would work with --data-binary (as per your question) but the parameters and the file data would both be accessed in a different way on the back end.

```
curl --data-binary '@test.txt' 'http://example.com?id=xxx&name=foo'
```